Are static libraries generally rebuilt entirely if one of the obj files that make them up is changed?
I know that if I have a project with a bunch of different translation units and change something only in that translation unit (what ends up in the obj file) is recompiled. Then linking with the executable seems to be quick. I'm just wondering, since static libraries are described as being a group of obj files placed together in one file is it generally the case that the OTHER obj files that constitute the static library don't need to be recompiled, only the obj file that changed? In other words does it work the same way with static libraries as it does with an executable? Change only one obj file and the others don't need to be recompiled?

Unless the build system author made a mistake, the answer is "yes". The Make behavior of sometimes removing intermediates comes to mind.

Hi, doesn't LTO matter in the picture? It shouldn't change the fact that untouched TU shouldn't be recompiled but i'm guessing it will have an impact on link time. Anyway its purely compiler/linker dependent. I don't think there is a standard for compilation and link.

Yes that is correct, only the changed module needs recompilation. However, changing something in a header file will require recompilation of every source module that includes that header. In either casse the library (whether static or dynamic) will then need to be rebuilt.

@OldBoy What I don't get is let's say you change one translation unit, that gets recompiled, then it has to link the recompiled version into the executable, which had many different obj files linked into it, how does does "patch" (so to speak) only the section that needs to be patched, because I didn't know that the make system kept track of the executable's binary structure. It seems to happen so quick when just one obj file changes.

That's a completely different question. Most linkers don't do incremental linking and just repeat the entire process from scratch. However, the underlying object files do not need to be rebuilt, only the library/executable.

The process of building a static library or an executable from a set of compiled objects doesn't usually patch an existing file.   If the output file (the library or the executable) exists, it will often either be deleted and recreated, or truncated to zero size.   Then data from the compiled objects and some additional bookkeeping data is copied to that file.   That process is usually relatively simple so involves much less time or computing resource than the process of compiling all of the object file(s) from source.

@Peter How's the process relatively simple? In the obj files you have compiled that could further be optimized, I think in MSVC the linker calls the compiler at the link stage. If the executable isn't patched but rebuilt that would necessarily mean linking (and compiling), depending if it's compiling at the link stage, into the executable all over again. I don't get how it works so fast in my case when just one obj file is changed.

Linking object files together has nothing to do with the make system. All that the make process does is provide the parameters (options and file names) that the linker or librarian needs to build the final file.

@OldBoy Doesn't the make system keep track of which obj files need rebuilding?

@ZebraFish - I think you're making unwarranted assumptions.   Build systems generally treat compilation (translating source files to object files) and the building of libraries or executables from those object files as distinct phases - and the make system (or IDE) orchestrates compiling (or recompiling) to build object files which are input to a later phase (to build either a library or an executable from the objects).   A smarter linker may optimise the structure of the executable somewhat, but doesn't recompile object files from source to do that.

@Zebrafish No, the make system merely processes a set of rules to build a target or targets from sets of source items. It has no way of knowing what has happened in previous executions of its script(s).


… since static libraries are described as being a group of obj files placed together in one file is it generally the case that the OTHER obj files that constitute the static library don't need to be recompiled, only the obj file that changed?

The traditional ar command has a switch, -r, for replacing individual modules within the archive (the library file). With this type of object library, it is entirely feasible to rebuild only the object modules that need changing and to update only those object modules in the library.

Are static libraries generally rebuilt entirely if one of the obj files that make them up is changed?

That is a question about practice rather than technological capability, as it asks what people do rather than what is possible. Without a survey of the world’s projects, we cannot definitively speak to what percentage of projects update their static libraries incrementally.
Incremental update of static libraries was motivated in part by relative computing expenses in the past. Keeping all the object modules available to rebuild the library or recompiling all the modules would have cost additional space or time. Costs are cheaper these days, and updating a library incrementally introduces a dependency on previous builds. So project designers may prefer to have a “simpler” build process that constructs a new static library rather than updating it incrementally.

In other words does it work the same way with static libraries as it does with an executable? Change only one obj file and the others don't need to be recompiled?

It is generally true that some set of changes to a project may require rebuilding some of its object modules and not others, and this is true whether a target is a static library or is an executable. However, there is a difference in that it is not uncommon that the static library can be updated incrementally by replacing some of its object modules and not others, whereas it is common that updating an executable requires rebuilding it from all the object modules.
In other words, to update a static library as maintained by ar, you only need the newly changed object modules available. The library will retain its unchanged modules. To update a traditional executable, you need all of the object modules available, as the executable is rebuilt from scratch using all the object modules.

Yes, that's the way I saw it,  that building a static library is kind of like concatenating the already built obj files, however building the executable is more complex, especially in cases where it's actually compiled at the link-stage and it's rebuilt. On my MSVC it does this so fast and I couldn't figure how. Then I found out about incremental linking, so I figured it was that, however I found out it's off, and I can't turn it on with link-time-code-generation on. Nevertheless it's really fast and I don't know how.
